# What does a grayed-out shortcut indicate?

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, desktop

This morning I notice I have a new shortcut on my desktop - "desktop.ini"

It is grayed out, yet I can open it and see the minimal contents, namely:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21769
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-183
```

I don't know how this "ghost" file got there, why it's there, or even whether it's a "rogue" file.

Does anybody have any insight on what would cause that file to suddenly appear with its washed-out appearance?

### UPDATE

I just realized - that file on the desktop is not a shortcut after all - it is the actual file. So where does this file normally belong? I'll move it back to there and get it to stop cluttering up my desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Windows uses these "hidden" system files to store metadata about the folder.  It is not a rogue or harmful file.  You can delete them but they'll probably come back.  Use the options others have given if you don't want them to be visible.

Comment: I know what kind of file it is; I just don't get why it will show up all of a sudden on my desktop as a shortcut.

Comment: Where does the shortcut point to?  Maybe it's there because you dragged or copied files from another folder that had the file in it.

Comment: No, I never drag files onto my desktop. Location is "C:\Users\clay\Desktop"

Comment: And I just noticed - it's not a shortcut at all - it is the actual file.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a system file, designated to be 'hidden'.  You can set folder preferences to Show/Hide Hidden Files/Folders if you like.  Common files are .BAT, .DLL, and .INI

Comment: Yes, I found this: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/6108/windows-7-what-is-the-desktop-ini-file-and-how-can-i-remove-it/

Answer (score 1):

The icon in question is grayed because it's a so-called System file. It is normally there, but is normally hidden.

Open Windows Explorer, then click on `Tools > Folder options` (you might have to press the ALT key first), then go to the `View` tab. Make sure `Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)` is checked. If it is, click on `Don't show hidden files, folders, or drives` (to turn off `Show hidden files, folders, and drives`) to make the icon disappear from the Desktop.

Comment: From where? I see no "Tools" either when right-clicking on the desktop, nor in Windows Exploder...

Comment: I added a better explanation of how to get to The folder options page.